# declare a Pair datatype using Z3 java API

Tags: java, z3

I am using Z3 java API. I need to define a set of pair elements e.x. {(e1,e2)...} I do not know how we can declare pair datatype in z3 using Java API?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a pair with the Z3 Java API as a free datatype with one constructor mkpair and two arguments as follows (untested pseudocode, assuming ctx is a z3.Context and with a pair of integers):

```
Array<String> argnames = new Array<String>("first", "second");
Array<z3.Sort> argsorts = new Array<z3.Sort>(ctx.getIntSort(), ctx.getIntSort());
z3.Constructor mkpair = ctx.mkConstructor("mkpair", "ispair", argnames, argsorts, null);
z3.DatatypeSort pair = ctx.mkDatatypeSort("pair", new Array<z3.Constructor>(mkpair));
```

For sets there is a builtin type, which you can constructor via

```
z3.SetSort setOfPairs = ctx.mkSetSort(pair);
```

An example expression mkpair(1, 2) would be built by

```
z3.Expr sample = ctx.mkApp(mkpair.ConstructorDecl(), ctx.mkInt(1), ctx.mkInt(2));
```

Comment: Do you know what the SetSort is translated to? AFAIK, Z3 doesn't have native support for set theory. Does it encode sets as arrays (as described in the Z3 guide, http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide)?